# Getting physical dimensions of screen in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, appkit

Is it possible to get the physical dimensions (millimeters or otherwise) of a given monitor with Python on macOS?

I was looking at [AppKit's NSScreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) but it only gives pixel resolution (via `frame`) and doesn't seem to report physical size. I'm not sure what other approach I could take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this info from [`CGDisplayScreenSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456599-cgdisplayscreensize), which according to the doc returns "the size of the specified display in millimeters".

The [Quartz](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/) Python library seems to have a binding for it:

```py
from Quartz import CGDisplayScreenSize, CGMainDisplayID

display_id = CGMainDisplayID()
dimensions = CGDisplayScreenSize(display_id)
print(dimensions)
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. If anybody is wondering, looks like you can also get the display ID from an `NSScreen` using `display_id = screen.deviceDescription()["NSScreenNumber"]`, and pass that to `CGDisplayScreenSize` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Quartz.CGDisplayScreenSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456599-cgdisplayscreensize):

> Returns the width and height of a display in millimeters.
> `func CGDisplayScreenSize(_ display: CGDirectDisplayID) -> CGSize`

```
import Quartz

def main() -> None:
    main_display_id = Quartz.CGMainDisplayID()
    width_mm, height_mm = Quartz.CGDisplayScreenSize(main_display_id)
    print(f'{width_mm = :.2f}, {height_mm = :.2f}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example output using a M1 Macbook Air:**

```
width_mm = 286.87, height_mm = 179.29
```